# Calculate top two performing product categories from Sales data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to build a KPI of top 2 performing product categories for each customer.
I have sales data with following relevant columns - 
customerid, product, product_category, order_qty, product_amt , order_date

I am using legacy SQL syntax in BQ.

Comment: Where is the product category?

Comment: I just edited the question, thanks for pointing that out @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a possible solution...

```
SELECT
  customer_id,
  product_category,
  order_qty
FROM (
  SELECT
    customerid, 
    product_category, 
    SUM(order_qty) AS order_qty,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY order_qty DESC) AS rn
  FROM
    [project:dataset.table] 
  GROUP BY
    1, 2
)
WHERE
  rn <= 2
ORDER BY
  1, 3 DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i came up with similar query. But i am hitting an error - Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. ORDER BY operator used too much memory.. (error code: resourcesExceeded)
My table contains 150 million rows with a size of 15.8 GB. 
I can only see the results by putting the limit, which is not the complete output

Comment: Could you try getting rid of outside order by clause (not the one in the PARTITION BY clause). Also BigQuery documentation discourages using ORDER BY on huge data sets

Comment: In your solution how can we create 2 columns, when rn=1 then category_1, when rn=2 then category_2.