# How to limit my results to only the rows I need?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

This is the code I have currently that pulls the top 2 contacts but because every company has more than 2 contacts when I bring in the USERID into picture (that is required) it gives me rows with all Userids for a company although they are not my top 2 Contacts.

```
select companyid, 
 userid,
(case when seqnum = 1 then username end) as  Contact1,
(case when seqnum = 2 then username end) as  Contact2,


from (
select *, row_number() over (partition by companyid order by username) as 
seqnum from 
( SELECT b.userid, username, a.companyid from [UsersInCompanies] a
JOIN [Companies] c on a.companyid = c.companyid 
join [aspnet_Users] b on a.userid = b.userid ) t ) l
```

Result set I'm getting

```
CompanyID Userid  Contact1  Contact2 
1         xyz-78  Jane Doe1  NULL    
1         uik-90  NULL       JD2    
1         jkl-70  NULL       NULL
1         abc-60  NULL       NULL
```

Desired result

```
CompanyID Userid  Contact1  Contact2 
1         xyz-78  JaneDoe1  NULL    
1         uik-90  NULL       JaneDoe2
```

Should I be using some sort of COUNT & TOP functions ?

Comment: Try filtering by `seqnum <= 2`

Comment: *Filtering in a `WHERE` clause at the end of your query: `WHERE seqnum <= 2`. Copy, paste, run, done.

Comment: You have an extra sub-query that isn't really necessary. [**This should get you there**](http://rextester.com/AHPYZ18908)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate top two performing product categories from Sales data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009033/calculate-top-two-performing-product-categories-from-sales-data)

Answer (score 1):

You need filtration (i.e. `seqnum <= 2`) , but i would rewrite it as :

```
with t as (
        SELECT b.userid, username, a.companyid, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.companyid order by b.username) as seqnum 
        FROM [UsersInCompanies] a INNER JOIN 
             [Companies] c 
             ON a.companyid = c.companyid INNER JOIN 
             [aspnet_Users] b 
             ON a.userid = b.userid
 )
select companyid, userid,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then username end) as  Contact1,
       (case when seqnum = 2 then username end) as  Contact2
from t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is cleaner

```
with cte as 
(
    SELECT b.userid, username, a.companyid, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.companyid order by b.username) as rn 
    FROM [UsersInCompanies] a 
    JOIN [Companies] c 
      ON a.companyid = c.companyid 
    JOIN [aspnet_Users] b 
      ON a.userid = b.userid
)
select ct1.*, cte2.username 
  from cte as cte1 
  join cte as cte2 
    on cte1.companyid = cte2.companyid
   and cte1.rn = 1
   and cte2.rn = 2
```